# "Device in use" phrasing

Tags: android, labels, text, settings

I'm making an android app, in it there's a settings section regarding notifications. There's a category of settings that apply only when the device is currently being used, and the category is labeled "While in use...".  My concern is it doesn't immediately communicate whether I mean the device or the app. What should I label this category of settings?

Comment: What do you mean by "being used", and can you give some examples of your current GUI text?

Comment: just specify and clarify e.g; "While device is in use"

Comment: Frankly, we need a little more information about what is this device about. Currently the answers are varying amount of guesses based on it is **On**, **awake**, **powered** etc. It would be beneficial if you give some more details about what exactly it means by in use. A weighing scale is in use when someone is standing on it, a car is in use when someone is driving it etc. Based on your device properties, the message can be more contextual.

Answer (score 1):

I think saying some version of "While device is in use" is clear. Just show a couple people the settings page and do a quick usability test to see if they are confused.

- While device in use
- While device is in use
- While using device

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions from my end:

- While the device is running
- For this device when awake
- For this working device
- While the device is on

You can shuffle between the words "working",'running','not in sleep','not in flight' and the like to go about your phrasing.

Comment: How do you know that any of these phrases are any better than just saying 'device in use'?

Comment: I'm not sure if these phrases reflect what the OP is asking. Just because a device is "running" or "on" doesn't mean it is "in use"... Also, some of these suggestions seem to include technical jargon. A user could get confused about what "running" means, for example.

Answer (score 0):

### While this device is powered on

Explain the exact cause and effect.  In this case, it sounds like you don't really care if the device is being used (interacted with) and mean to say

> the settings below will take effect anytime your **device is on**.